# Too many initialisers error

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to run below code. I am getting too many initialiser error. I know some problem initialise the array here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

int array[16][5]={
    {0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1},
    {0,0,0,1,0},  
    {0,0,0,1,1},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1},
    {0,0,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,1,1},
    {0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1 },
    {0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0 },
    {0,1,1,0,1},
    {0,1,1,1,0 },
    {0,1,1,1,1}, 
    {1,0,0,0,0} 
};

int main()
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("welcome");
        }

    }
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Please don't link us to code.

Comment: i tried to post code . Here every time it seems like you have code here need to update error

Comment: simply type the text, we'll help you format it

Answer (score 6):

Your array has 17 elements, not 16

Answer (score 1):

You've declared an array with **16** rows of **5** `int`s in each row. But you wrote 17 rows instead, exactly as the error message says - You're defining it with more elements than it should accept.

```
           ↓
int array[16][5]={
    {0,0,0,0,0},   //0
    {0,0,0,0,1},   //1
    {0,0,0,1,0},   //2
    {0,0,0,1,1},   //3
    {0,0,1,0,0},   //4
    {0,0,1,0,1},   //5
    {0,0,1,1,0},   //6
    {0,0,1,1,1},   //7
    {0,1,0,0,0},   //8
    {0,1,0,0,1 },  //9
    {0,1,0,1,0},   //10
    {0,1,0,1,1},   //11
    {0,1,1,0,0 },  //12
    {0,1,1,0,1},   //13
    {0,1,1,1,0 },  //14
    {0,1,1,1,1},   //15
    {1,0,0,0,0}    //16
    //Total of 17 elements
};
```